# Variable does not go into local storage and does not appear on other page. (JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, local-storage

I am trying to create a scoreboard for my game by using local storage to carry over the score variable after a game is finished by a user. However, this is not working for some reason. I am relatively new to coding so I did some research on local storage but couldn't get the code to work to no avail. Could someone help me with this code thanks.

Page 1:

```
    <html>
    <title>Level Selector</title>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="400"></canvas>

    <style type="text/css">
        canvas { background: #eee; }
    </style>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener('load', draw);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 2;//Ball is moving in x direction at a constant rate
    var dy = -2;//Ball is moving in y direction at a constant rate
    var ballRadius = 10;//To see if ball is colliding with brick/canvas
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
    var rightPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'right arrow' key is not pressed.
    var leftPressed = false;//This variable is false because the 'left arrow' key is not pressed.
    var brickRowCount = 5;
    var brickColumnCount = 8;
    var brickWidth = 75;
    var brickHeight = 20;
    var brickPadding = 10;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
    var score = 0;
    var lives = 3;
    var paused = false;

    var bricks = [];//this is an array holding all the bricks
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[c] = [];
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };//If status is '1' then draw it. However, is status is '0', fill in with background
    }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);//Functions only when key is pressed
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);//Functions only when key is not pressed
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);//Functions only when mouse curcor moves


    //keyCode(39) is the code for the 'right arrow' key and keyCode(37) is the code for the 'left arrow' key
    function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
    }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
    }
    }


    function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
    var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;//This represents the hoizontal mouse movement.
    if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
    }
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', pauseGameKeyHandler, false);

    function pauseGameKeyHandler(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){
    case 80: //p
      togglePause();
      break;
    }

    }

    function togglePause() {
    paused = !paused;
    draw();
    }

    /*************************************************************/




    // NEW
    const ballPowerupHalfWidth = 30;
    const paddlePowerupHalfWidth = 30;

    let ballPowerups = [];
    let paddlePowerups = [];

    // This function adds powerup to random position
    function addPowerups() {
    // I check only if none exist, you could
    // add more than 1 powerup if you want
    if (ballPowerups.length < 1) {
    // otherwise half the triangle could be outside canvas
    const padding = 50;
    const xMin = 0 + padding;
    const xMax = canvas.width - padding;
    const yMin = 0 + padding;
    const yMax = canvas.height - padding;

    ballPowerups.push({
        x: Math.floor(Math.random()*(xMax-xMin+1)+xMin),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random()*(yMax-yMin+1)+yMin),
    });
    }

    // I check only if none exist, you could
    // add more than 1 powerup if you want
    if (paddlePowerups.length < 1) {
    // otherwise half the triangle could be outside canvas
    const padding = 50;
    const xMin = 0 + padding;
    const xMax = canvas.width - padding;
    const yMin = 0 + padding;
    const yMax = canvas.height - padding;

    paddlePowerups.push({
      x: Math.floor(Math.random()*(xMax-xMin+1)+xMin),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random()*(yMax-yMin+1)+yMin),
    });
    }
    }


    // NEW: do all collision detections
    function doCollisionDetection() {
    // ball powerups
    ballPowerups.forEach((powerup, i) => {
    rectangleCollisionDetection(
        {x: powerup.x, y: powerup.y}, 
      {w: ballPowerupHalfWidth, h: ballPowerupHalfWidth}, 
      () => {
        console.log('BALL POWERUP COLLISION');
        // remove powerup
        ballPowerups.splice(i, 1);
         dy = dy/2
         setTimeout(() => { dy=2 }, 5000)

        // to make effect last 10 seconds:
        // 1. add effect
        // 2. and setTimeout(() => { /* code that removes effect */ }, 10000);
    });
    });

    // paddle powerups
    paddlePowerups.forEach((powerup, i) => {
    rectangleCollisionDetection(
        {x: powerup.x, y: powerup.y}, 
      {w: ballPowerupHalfWidth, h: ballPowerupHalfWidth}, 
      () => {
        console.log('PADDLE POWERUP COLLISION');
        // remove powerup
        paddlePowerups.splice(i, 1);
        paddleHeight = paddleHeight*1.5
        paddleWidth = paddleWidth*1.5
        setTimeout(() => { paddleHeight=10; }, 10000)
    });
    });

    // bricks
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if(b.status == 1) {
        rectangleCollisionDetection(b, {w: brickWidth, h: brickHeight}, () => {
            console.log('BRICK COLLISION');
            dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATULATIONS!");
            window.location = "Intro Screen.html";
          }
        });
      }
    }
}


    // NEW: collision detection between ball and rectangle shaped
    // collision boundary (only need center(x, y) and half width)
    function rectangleCollisionDetection(center, size, callback) {
    if(
    x > center.x && 
    x < center.x+size.w && 
    y > center.y && 
    y < center.y+size.h
    ) {
    callback && callback();
    }
    }



    function drawBallpowerup() {
    ballPowerups.forEach(powerup => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(powerup.x, powerup.y);
    ctx.lineTo(powerup.x+ballPowerupHalfWidth, powerup.y+ballPowerupHalfWidth);
    ctx.lineTo(powerup.x+ballPowerupHalfWidth*2, powerup.y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#42f445";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    });
    }

    function drawPaddlepowerup() {
    paddlePowerups.forEach(powerup => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(powerup.x, powerup.y);
    ctx.lineTo(powerup.x+paddlePowerupHalfWidth, powerup.y+paddlePowerupHalfWidth);
    ctx.lineTo(powerup.x+paddlePowerupHalfWidth*2, powerup.y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ce6210";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    });
    }


    // my big changes end here

    /*************************************************************/

    //this is the score variable of the game
    function drawScore() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
    }

    //this is the lives variable of the game
    function drawLives() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-65, 20);
    }

    //this creates the ball
    function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    }

    //this creates the paddle
    function drawPaddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    }

    //this creates the bricks
    function drawBricks() {
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (c*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
    }
    }

    function draw() {
    // clears canvas content from previous frame
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawBall();//this code draws the ball onto the canvas
    drawPaddle();//this code draws the paddle onto the canvas
    drawBricks();//this code draws the bricks onto the canvas

    addPowerups();
    doCollisionDetection();

    drawScore();//this code draws the score variable onto the canvas
    drawLives();//this code draws the lives variable onto the canvas

    drawBallpowerup();
    drawPaddlepowerup();

    //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'x' direction (Left/Right wall)
    if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
    }

    //Reverse Ball movement when the ball collides with wall in 'y' direction (Top/Bottom wall)
    if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
    }   else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
    if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;//If the ball collides with the paddle,  the ball is rebounded in the opposite direction.
    }
    else {
      lives--;
      if(!lives) {
        alert("GAME OVER");
        localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    }
        window.location = "Intro Screen.html";
      }
      else {
        x = canvas.width/2;
        y = canvas.height-30;
        dx = 2;
        dy = -2;
        paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
      }
    }
    }

    if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
    paddleX += 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the positive x direction
    }
    else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {//limits paddle movement in between the canvas width
    paddleX -= 7;//Paddle shifts 7 pixels in the negative x direction
    }

    x += dx;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in
    y += dy;//Ball is updated by painting it over each position it moves in

    if(!paused) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    }

    draw();
    </script>

    <body onload="draw();>


    </body>

</html>
```

Page 2:

```
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score"));
```

}

When I run it and after playing the game, the score should be added onto the scoreboard in decending order (highest to lowest). I have trouble bringing over the variable.

Comment: is control coming in block where you are adding it to localstorage

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: I bet you're getting null or undefined because you didn't `toString()` your retrieval of what's in localStorage. Try: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score").toString();` Also might help to stringify your storage like so: `localStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score));`

Comment: @AmanSeth I am not sure what you are talking about. I'm not sure whether it saves on localstorage or not. If I have to, I can use cookies instead but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: @epascarello None that I know of

Comment: @I.R.R. Ok i'll try that. So in Page 1 do I use this: "document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score").toString();". And in page 2 do I use: "localStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score));" ??

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner I'd use both as that's good defensive coding practice. By doing this you make sure you don't leave the object type as something other than a string. This may or may not solve your issue but I cannot tell you how many hours I wasted debugging because I did not code defensively and made sure I input/output exactly the type of data I need.

Comment: @I.R.R. so i use both lines on both pages?

Comment: Yes, stringify it when you set it in localStorage, toString() it when you get it from localStorage, regardless of where you are calling these two localStorage methods (`.setItem()` and `.getItem()`) because localStorage only handles strings.

Comment: @I.R.R. I believe the program does save the score however it does not appear on the other page.

Comment: @I.R.R. I had a look on console commands and nothing shows up about the score value being saved onto local storage. I have absolutely no idea how this works.

Comment: If you are using Chrome then you can check in the Developer Tools (F12) -> Application -> Local Storage -> <your-website-address> and you will get a table of keys and values stored in localStorage for the site. If your key and value was stored correctly you'd find it there.

Comment: @I.R.R. Indeed Storage only stores strings, so calling toString at getting is useless.

Comment: From where are you executing your website? Do you have a webserver setup and do you access it from the `http[s]://` protocol or from the disk directly, i.e from the `file://` protocol? Every page is considered a different domain from the file protocol, and this means they'll all have their own Storage area, that you won't be able to share. (Chrome going farther in considering every Document their own domain, making localStorage a simple global object...

Comment: @Kaiido This is a file on my storage. Not a website. I'm entirely not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: @I.R.R. It has stored correctly but I'm not sure how to make it go onto Page 2

Answer (score 1):

While there are no standard specifications about it, most browsers will consider different pages served from the *file://* protocol as being *different-origin*.

This means your two pages will be considered as *different-origin* and will thus have their own Storage Area that they won't be able to share, just like you won't be able to access the Storage Area from *www.xxxxx.com* from *www.yyyyy.com*.

To overcome this limitation, the easiest is to [run a local web-server on your machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+a++local+web-server). Many OSes comes with preinstalled such server, and all it requires is to activate it, and for the ones that don't do it, there are many free and easy solutions.

And if you are planning to play with web standards, it's a must have anyway.

Comment: All I have to do is retrieve the local storage and display the value onto a table. `if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score"));
}` I am trying to retieve it and display it on this page

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner I'd go with this answer because the other potentially viable (really stretching that definition) involves more complications and potential security risks.

Comment: @I.R.R. damn, ok I'll see if I can do it

Comment: @I.R.R. This is too hard, Imma just leave this out. Thanks for the help anyways :D

Comment: @Rolls_Reus_0wner if you're on windows and an absolute beginner try this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/ . It's okay to take a break for some space but don't give up. Persistence pays.